# remember column width, position and (in)visible

Tags: extjs, grid, width

Once again a question about extjs.

I use EXT 4.0.2 and have a couple of grids. How can i store the settings for the column width and position? Everytime i load the page everything is back to basic and that starts to annoy me :)

Thanks,

Toby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [`stateful`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-stateful)`: true` statement to grid's config.

For this to work you also should enable state manager:

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider({
    expires: new Date(new Date().getTime()+(1000*60*60*24*7)), //7 days from now
}));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. This fix the position and visible or invisible...great. But column width is not working. is this because there is a forcefit?

Comment: @TobyJustus, it looks like forcefit affects restoring the columns. But  I can't say that it's not working completely([example](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/LBbGP/embedded/result/)). Without forcefit - [everything is okay](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/pKMxY/embedded/result/)

Comment: thanks for the example. I will remove the forcefit. After all it is more important to select the width yourself then let the browser force it. Thanks!

Comment: I've needed to add 'Ext.state.CookieProvider' to the class requires to make it work.